# Are there any concerns I should have about storing a Python Lock object in a Beaker session?

Tags: python, concurrency, pylons, beaker

There is a certain page on my website where I want to prevent the same user from visiting it twice in a row.  To prevent this, I plan to create a Lock object (from Python's threading library).  However, I would need to store that across sessions.  Is there anything I should watch out for when trying to store a Lock object in a session (specifically a Beaker session)?

Comment: What do you mean exactly by 'visiting twice in a row'?

Comment: The page the user visits spawns a child process.  If two of these processes are launched at once, they can crash each other.  If the user were to visit the page quickly, 2 or more times, then 2 or more of these processes could be launched and bring each other down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Storing a threading.Lock instance in a session (or anywhere else that needs serialization) is a terrible idea, and presumably you'll get an exception if you try to (since such an object cannot be serialized, e.g., it cannot be `pickle`d).  A traditional approach for cooperative serialization of processes relies on [file locking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_locking) (on "artificial" files e.g. in a directory such as `/tmp/locks/<username>` if you want the locking to be per-user, as you indicate).  I believe the wikipedia entry does a good job of describing the general area; if you tell us what OS you're running order, we might suggest something more specific (unfortunately I do not believe there is a cross-platform solution for this).

Comment: I also realized that the Pylons/Beaker session itself has support for locking.

Answer (score 0):

I just realized that this was a terrible question since locking a lock and saving it to the session takes two steps thus defeating the purpose of the lock's atomic actions.